# The reason behind this answer in the textbook?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following:
[image]

Calculate the orthogonal vector: [image]

The answer in the text book is: [image]

However when I calculate it I get the following:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2^{2}+0^{2}+2^{2}}}\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\ 
0\\ 
2
\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\ 
0\\ 
2
\end{bmatrix}$$

I realize it is the same answer, however why did the textbook divide by 2 to result in the vector $\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Because you can I suppose. It's looks kind of neater, but that's just personal taste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You computed $e/\|e\|$, but you missed the obvious fact that $\sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{2}$, and therefore your result coincides with that provided by the book. 
Unless you mean a different thing, the textbook just simplifies the square root of $8$, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Indeed I did miss it!

Answer (score 1):

That's a unit vector.
There's an infinite number of orthogonal vectors.
The book gave you a vector containing one's so you can easily parametrize it.

Answer (score 1):

You get the same answer when you normalize $\vec{v}$ as when you normalize $2\vec{v}$.  They cancelled the factor $2$ because it gave smaller, simpler numbers, and the same answer.  It is just like replacing 2/4 with 1/2.